# "...my passion for teaching and my knowledge of the English language makes me" or "...make me..."?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, verb-agreement, compound-subjects, coordinating-conjunctions

I am working on my resume. I don’t  know if I should use **make** instead of **makes** in this sentence.

> I believe that my passion for teaching and my knowledge of the English
>   language **makes** me an ideal candidate for a teaching position at your
>   school

Comment: Often, with these kinds of things, both will work - and you are best guided by what sounds right to your ear. Personally, were it me, in this instance I would use "make".

Comment: two things make you, no s.

Comment: Hopefully you got the job before they saw this ELU post...

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly confident the sentence is **incorrect** as is. It should read:

"*I believe that my passion for teaching and my knowledge of the English language **make** me an ideal candidate...*"

---

I would argue this because it is your passion and your knowledge (i.e. 2 things) that **together make** you an ideal candidate.

Simplified, the sentence could read as "*This and that **make** me an ideal candidate*"

Answer (score 1):

This grammatical issue is called *concord* or *agreement*, specifically here the agreement of the subject and the verb. In other words, a singular subject requires a singular and a plural subject requires a plural verb form:

> - Harry *is* marrying Meghan.
> - Meghan and Harry *are* getting married.

This is known as *formal* agreement. But there is also *notional agreement*. This exists when a coordinated subject, that formally requires a plural verb, is conceived by the speaker as a single item:

> - Fish and chips is my favourite meal.
> - The hammer and sickle is a communist symbol that was adopted during the Russian Revolution. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_and_sickle)

*Garner's Modern English Usage* (p778), in the section on *Subject-verb agreement* has this advice on *compound subjects joined conjunctively*:

> If two or more subjects joined by *and* are different and separable,
>   they take a plural verb. ... But sometimes the two subjects joined by
>   *and* express a single idea, and hence should take a singular verb.

It is clear to me that *my passion for teaching* and *my knowledge of the English language* are different and separable. Hence the verb should be in the plural form and the correct sentence reads:

> I believe that my passion for teaching and my knowledge of the English
>   language **make** me an ideal candidate for a teaching position at
>   your school.