# have or has following "something and something"

Tags: have

My work experience and education have provided me with an extensive background in business.

Do i use have/has here?

Comment: It could go either way.  "Work experience and education" could be regarded as two items or a single thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["...my passion for teaching and my knowledge of the English language makes me" or "...make me..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446733/my-passion-for-teaching-and-my-knowledge-of-the-english-language-makes-me-o) (I'm sure there's a prior duplicate on 'agreement following a coordinated subject: formal or logical, and if logical, which way does this one swing?'.)

Answer (score 0):

(both) My work experience and education have (both) provided me- with "both being implied in either part of the sentence.

However, this is not a strong opening sentence for a resume.  There is nothing to suggest that your work experience, or your education provided an "extensive background in business."

"I have an extensive background in business, beginning with my x years, at X school, majoring in x, followed by x years working in x areas of business."

My work experience and education have provided me with an extensive background in business.

Do i use have/has here?

Answer (score 0):

It's ambiguous. You could be talking about two separate things or a single, combined thing.

More explicitly:

> **Both** my work experience and education **have** provided me with an extensive background in business.

Or:

> **The combination** *of* my work experience and education **has** provided me with an extensive background in business.

---

So, you can use either one. If you don't make your meaning explicit, it will be assumed by the verb form you choose. (Nobody will think that you got it wrong.)  If you use *have*, it will be interpreted as two things; if you use *has*, it will be interpreted as a single thing.